# How can I format a given date of only day and month with moment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am receiving on an object something like this `3/19` and I need to know how can I make readable by moment because I have to compare that date with the current date which I am also getting from moment.

```
export const themes: Theme[] = [{
  theme: 'spring',
  bannerImage: 'spring.jpg',
  cssOverride: 'springThemeStyles.scss',
  endDate: '6/19',
  startDate: '3/19'
}];

export const getActiveTheme = (): any => {
  const now = moment().format('MM/DD');

  return themes.map((t: Theme) => {
    if (t.startDate >= now || t.endDate <= now) {
      if (t.theme.toLowerCase() === 'spring') {
        return require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss');
      }

      return null;
    }
  });
};
```

Right now this is validation is not working: `(t.startDate >= now || t.endDate <= now)`

But if I do something like this: `moment(t.endDate)` it says is an invalid data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Couldn't you add the current year on `endDate` and `startDate`? In my opinion the `if` comparison is not working because the types (string and Date obj) are not comparable. Also, moment probably cannot create a date only based on MM/DD because there are multiple possible results (2020, 2019, 2018, etc). I think if you have like `endDate: moment('2020/06/19')` you would be able to compare them later to the current date and time in the `getActiveTheme`.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing you are missing is that you need to tell Moment what format the input is in using the [string + format syntax](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

You should also use the built-in Moment.js methods for comparing dates.

```
export const themes: Theme[] = [{
  theme: 'spring',
  bannerImage: 'spring.jpg',
  cssOverride: 'springThemeStyles.scss',
  endDate: '6/19',
  startDate: '3/19'
}];

export const getActiveTheme = (): any => {
  const now = moment();
  const format = 'MM/DD';

  return themes.map((t: Theme) => {
    if (moment(t.startDate, format).isSameOrAfter(now) 
        || moment(t.endDate, format).isSameOrBefore(now)) {
      if (t.theme.toLowerCase() === 'spring') {
        return require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss');
      }

      return null;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This is not working. If I log this `console.log(moment(themes[0].startDate, format));` I get this -> https://monosnap.com/file/YThfI8uSJUsGHltfY55cfbTvhjOmNS

Comment: @Reacting That is entirely expected. That is what a `Moment` object looks like. Perhaps you were under the misunderstanding that Moment.js worked with and always returned standard JS `Date` objects? That is not the case - it returns its own `Moment` object, which can be converted to a JS Date using `momentObject.toDate()`.